# Munkres Exercise 70.1

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

This is question number 1 from section 70 (The Seifert-van Kampen Theorem) in Munkres.

> Assume the hypotheses of the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem.
>
> Suppose that the homomorphism $i_*$ induced by the inclusion $i : U \cap V \rightarrow X$ is trivial.
>
> (a) Show that $j_1$ and $j_2$ induce an epimorphism
>   $$h: (\pi_1(U, x_0)\space / \space N_1)\space * \space (\pi_1(V, x_0)\space / \space N_2)\rightarrow \pi_1(X,x_0) $$
>   where $N_1$ is the least normal subgroup of $\pi_1(U, x_0)$ containing image $i_1$ and $N_2$ is the least normal subgroup of $\pi_1(V, x_0)$ containing image $i_2$.
>
> (b) Show that $h$ is an isomorphism
>
> Note that $i_1$, $i_2$, $j_1$, and $j_2$ are homomorphisms induced by the inclusion map such that:
>   $$i_1 : \pi_1(U \cap V, x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(U, x_0) $$
>   $$i_2 : \pi_1(U \cap V, x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(V, x_0) $$
>   $$j_1 : \pi_1(U , x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(X, x_0) $$
>   $$j_2 : \pi_1(V, x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(X, x_0) $$

Here is my attempt at part (a): Since $N$ is generated by elements of the form $i_i(w) \space * \space i_j(w)^{-1} $ where $w \in \pi_1(U \cap V)$, it contains the element $i_i(w) \space * \space identity $. Hence, it contains the elements of that form so it follows that it contains $N_1$. For similar reasoning, it will also contain $N_2$.

Since by Van Kampen, we have an isomorphism between $(\pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V)) \space / \space N$ and $\pi_1(X)$, and $N$ contains $N_1$ and $N_2$, it follows that $(\pi_1(U, x_0)\space / \space N_1)\space * \space (\pi_1(V, x_0)\space / \space N_2) \supseteq (\pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V)) \space / \space N$. Thus, the map $h$ is surjective.

Comment: This looks like an interesting question, surprised no one answered it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument for surjective is correct. Actually, this problem can be sovled by using purely group theory and constructing push out. We can directly show $h$ is an isomorphism.

To simplify the notation, use $\pi_1(U\cap V)$, $\pi_1(U)$ etc. to replace $\pi_1(U\cap V,x_0)$, $\pi_1(U,x_0)$ etc. Notice that $i: \pi_{1}(U\cap V)\to \pi_{1}(U\cup V)$ is composed by $j_{1}$ and $i_{1}$, so $i=j_{1}\circ i_{1}=j_{2}\circ i_{2}=0$.

The diagram commutes. (Sorry I don't have enough reputation so I cannot embed a picture, I'll update it as soon as I get 10)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TlEv.png)

$j_{1}\circ i_{1}=0$ indicates $j_{1}(i_{1}(\pi_{1}(U\cap V)))=\{e\}< \pi_{1}(U\cup V)$. $N_{1}$ is the smallest group containing $i_{1}(\pi_{1}(U\cap V))$, which means $N_{1}< \ker(j_{1})$. By the first isomorphism theorem, we have the following diagram commutes:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdZfB.png)

Here $q_{1}: \pi_{1}(U) \to \pi_{1}(U) /N_{1}$ is the canonical homomorphism and $f_{1}$ is the induced homomorphism, $f_{1}\circ q_{1}=j_{1}$. Applying similar argument to $\pi_{1}(V) /N_{2}$, we can immediately get the following commutative diagram:

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ongVS.png)

Now we show $\pi_{1}(U\cup V)$ is the push out of $\pi_{1}(V) /N_{2}\xleftarrow{q_{2}\circ i_{2}}\pi_{1}(U\cap V)\xrightarrow{q_{2}\circ i_{2}} \pi_{1}(U) /N_{1}$. Suppose there is a group $G$ s.t. the following diagram commutes, we need to find a unique homomorphism $u: \pi_{1}(U\cup V)\to G$.

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQKiU.png)

Van Kampen theorem implies the $\pi_{1}(U\cup V)$ is the push out of $\pi_{1}(V)\xleftarrow{i_{2}}\pi_{1}(U\cap V)\xrightarrow{i_{2}} \pi_{1}(U)$. So there is a unique homomorphism $u: \pi_{1}(U\cup V)\to G$ s.t. the diagram commutes.

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjy1k.png)

Thus the $u$ is the unique homomorphism s.t. the following diagram commutes. $\pi_{1}(U\cap V)$ is the push out of $\pi_{1}(V) /N_{2}\xleftarrow{q_{2}\circ i_{2}}\pi_{1}(U\cap V)\xrightarrow{q_{2}\circ i_{2}} \pi_{1}(U) /N_{1}$. Notice that $q_{1}\circ i_{1}$ will send $\pi_{1}(U\cap V)$ to the identity element of $\pi(U) /N_{1}$. $q_{1}\circ i_{1}$ is a trivial homomorphism, so as $q_{2}\circ i_{2}$. The push out of $\pi_{1}(V) /N_{2}\xleftarrow{q_{2}\circ i_{2}}\pi_{1}(U\cap V)\xrightarrow{q_{2}\circ i_{2}} \pi_{1}(U) /N_{1}$ is isomorphic to the free product of $\pi_{1}(U) /N_{1}$ and $\pi_{1}(V) /N_{2}$. We finally have $h: \pi_{1}(U) /N_{1}*\pi_{1}(V) /N_{2}\to \pi_{1}(U\cup V)$ induced by $j_{1}$ and $j_{2}$ an isomorphism.

[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9APkv.png)